# Counting tables by it's DISTINCT

Tags: html

So my table have such records

TABLE

```
ID    Department

1     Finance
2     Engineering
3     IT
4     Finance
5     IT
6     IT
```

I should be able to get:

```
Count Department
3     IT
2     Finance
1     Engineering
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There might be an issue as well if your records do not have a quit date for employees that are still employed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE` to restrict the rows.

```
SELECT id, 1 AS valid, Department
FROM RECORDS
WHERE DATEDIFF(quitDate, hiredDate) < 730 AND Department = 'IT'
```